# Почему не видно тень в Firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox

Почему не видно `box-shadow` с `1px` в браузере **Firefox** ?
И как можно это исправить ?

Вот пример:

```css
* {
  font-family: arial;
}

.box1 {
  padding: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px black;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px black; /* не помогает */
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.box2 {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1">Where is my<br>shadow ?!</div>
<div class="box2">My is here :P</div>
```

**Firefox** обновил до последней версии `56.0.2 (64-bit)`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: смотри ответ внизу.

Comment: У меня левый блок отображается абсолютно одинаково и в фаерфоксе, и в хроме — однопиксельная тень есть. Я не понял, в чём проблема?

Comment: @andreymal У меня последня версия `Firefox 56.0.2 (64-bit)` и вот `screenshot` : https://photos.app.goo.gl/s9kRWuMSD4a8JqsY2

Comment: Разочарую, у меня последняя версия:) Firefox 58.  https://photos.app.goo.gl/JqzvtI4UNPciFWK12  тень (есть, или нет, но отличия есть)

Comment: @ДенисКотляров тогда я даже не знаю что мне делать :(

Comment: Этот фаерфокс еще не вышел, если что) но скоро он выйдет:))

Comment: Ctrl-0 уже пробовали нажимать?  На картинке видно очень бледную тень

Comment: Кстати да, в старом фаере видно тень есть, правда маленькое очертание ее.

Comment: @AlexeyTen Вот удивило, если увеличить размер страницы через `Ctrl` и `+` то тень появляется, но если размер 100% или меньше то она исчезает. С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: С толщиной тени, наверное...

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  font-family: arial;
}

.box1 {
  padding: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px #000, inset 0px 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.box2 {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1">Where is my<br>shadow ?!</div>
<div class="box2">My is here :P</div>
```

Comment: или просто: box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px #000

Comment: Мне нужно именно мягкую тень как во втором случае.

Comment: @Cristian а как вы предлагаете запихнуть мягкую тень в всего один пиксель? Нарисуйте нам, пожалуйста.

Comment: @andreymal в `chrome` как-то работает

Comment: Ответ получите тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28800789/why-is-this-shadow-not-working-in-firefox

Comment: @Cristian в моём Chrome тень нифига не мягкая, не знаю откуда у вас она мягкая